# redirect back to previous page php

Tags: php, session

I am trying to redirect a user back to the page he/she were after successful login but it is not working right for me.

The problem is that instead of redirecting to the previous page it redirects to account.php..

**Edit**: I already have session started on another page and I am including that file.

The main page... index.php

```
<?php 
 include_once("models/config.php");
$_SESSION['page'] = 'index.php';
?>
```

And here is login php..

```
 if(isset($_SESSION["page"]) && is_object($_SESSION["page"])) //check if session exists
               {
 //Redirect a user to the previous page
 header("Location:".$_SESSION['page']);
                }
 else{header("Location:account.php");die();}
```

Comment: You did include `session_start();` somewhere, right?

Comment: yes I did. Sorry I forgot to put it here.

Comment: You need to include that in your code. Otherwise, I'll be askin' as will others ;-)

Comment: You see now? Someone posted an answer, and stands at being wrong. "Forgot"... hm.. my supplier wouldn't be happy if I told them "I mailed the envelope, but I FORGOT to put the CHEQUE inside" (wink) Please update your question with your "actual" code.

Comment: `$_SESSION["page"]` is not an object

Comment: Is the $_SESSION variable and object?

Comment: Oh boy this will get complicated. Another FRED.

Comment: Luckily I can still tell by your tone who's who :-)

Comment: @JonathonReinhart *"your tone"* = ?

Comment: To to OP: the **real** problem is that you probably copy/pasted some code that included the is_object call, and didn't stop and ask "huh what does this do?" so instead of trying to understand, you came to Stackoverflow. The answer here really is to RTFM, sorry.

Comment: @Fred it wasn't a malicious comment, you're upfront and sound funny.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I knew that. As you are also. One has to be, just not to lay it on too thick (lol). I can remember the first time you posted "RTFM" from another post; I got that "right away" ;-)

Comment: `$my_tone="My_Signature";`

Comment: Sometimes they just need to "Read The inFormational Manual".

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Ahem.... um.... yeah, that's it "inFormational", got it. (grin)

Comment: And [**We have a WINNER!**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18108381/1415724) I think I'm going to make this part of my new signature. @JonathonReinhart

Comment: The problem is, without people leaving firm comments, there is no motivation for the OP to *not* return with his next foolish question that could have been better answered by doing real debugging, instead of crowd-sourcing it to SO.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart True, however sessions can get pretty tricky at times, it depends on how much of the "inFormational" manual was actual "read". Cheers (*Peace brother*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `exit` or else it will continue to process the rest of the script.

```
if(!empty($_SESSION["page"])) //check if session exists
{
   //Redirect a user to the previous page
   header("Location:".$_SESSION['page']);
   exit;
}
else{header("Location:account.php");exit;}
```

As Christopher Morrissey stated, $_SESSION['page'] won't be an object. Just make sure that the variable exists and has a value using !empty.